# Can a Heroku app interface with Amazon EC2 instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, heroku

I am toying around with building a rails app in the near future and using Heroku to host it, but the app will need to interact with EC2 instances through SSH (unless I can find a better way).  I probably could build a pseudo API...but direct console access would be easier.  I am going to need the following:

1) Run commands on the EC2 console

2) Read the results

3) dynamically start and stop ec2 instances (a little unrelated but I am curious if heroku can do this)

I know heroku hosts their infrastructure on EC2, so latency would be grean and it would probably be more straight forward to just host my own rails server on an EC2 instance, but I really like the automation and tools available within Heroku.

Comment: The http://amazon-ec2.rubyforge.org/ gem could be of use to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EC2 specific: http://rubygems.org/gems/amazon-ec2

Console Commands/Results: http://rubygems.org/gems/net-ssh

Both these Gems should address my issue.  Thanks [Zabba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/382818/zabba) for the ec2 gem.  I am a little new to rails, and should have started looking there.  I love how easy it is to install new functionality into the language.